# Heroku fails on install pip requirements

Tags: python, heroku, pip, setuptools

Something very strange is happening in Heroku, I normally install my packages when I do a git push heroku master, but now what worked for months for me not work anymore.

Here is the error:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Obtaining django-widget-tweaks from git+https://github.com/julianogouveia/django-widget-tweaks/#egg=django-widget-tweaks (from -r /tmp/build_843fc05109f047351641f1b9e1db069d/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/julianogouveia/django-widget-tweaks/ to /app/.heroku/src/django-widget-tweaks
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
remote:               or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
remote:               or: -c --help-commands
remote:               or: -c cmd --help
remote:            
remote:            error: invalid command 'egg_info'
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /app/.heroku/src/django-widget-tweaks/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to partnersbit-prod.
```

What is more crazy about is that the egg_info error is a setuptools pip error, and the heroku always use the last version of pip with setuptools.

Someone has a ideia to how to start debugging this on heroku? The heroku documentation doesn't say anything about this and the stackoverflow already opened issue about this problem is incomplete and not well documented.

Answer (score 2):

What seems is that Heroku is doing some enhancements in the python-3.6.4 runtime and this are causing this egg_info error. I solved by now, changing the python runtime version from 3.6.4 to the 3.6.3 version.

I'll not close this question until I know how to go back to 3.6.4 version without errors.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was very helpful changing in `runtime.txt` python-3.6.4 -> python-3.6.3 -> python-3.6.4 and send it in separate pushes.